# SqlPackage failing - [sys] reference not resolved

Tags: tsqlt

Im try to execute our db unit tests during PR builds.  I have a solution with the main database project and a unit test project that references it, plus master.  I can run SqlPackage on my local machine but on the build server (in a docker container) I get this:

```
09:29:35   *** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
09:29:35   Error SQL0: The reference to the external element with the name '[sys]|[sys].[indexes].[compression_delay]' could not be resolved. No such element exists.
09:29:35   
09:29:35   An error occurred while adding references.  Deployment cannot continue.
09:29:35   WARNING: Error in processing the deploy report : SQL Package failed with exit
09:29:35   code 1
09:29:35   Process exited with code 0
```

Im thinking it cant find the master.dacpac file but it's there.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you double check that you are using the correct version of the dacpac corresponding to the sql server version set in the project properties?

Comment: And also, that that version matches the build server‘s SQL Server version.

Comment: Yes, your probably right, but I cant get the docker image to work locally as it's windows and I cant find the dockerfile or anyone who knows where it is.  Problems with working with a large team....

Comment: Just add a `SELECT @@VERSION` somewhere in the build. It’s a good practice anyway when working with freshly spun-up instances in an automated pipeline.